# Expandable listview doesnot work properly with height as wrap content

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a expandable list inside Nested Scroll View . The list is dynamic and i get the details from the api, so i cannot set a fixed height.There are lots of other widget below and above the expandable listview. But when i set the height to wrap content only the first item header is shown. I have tried the solutions in the previous question but they are just a workaround and i want it to be the proper way for my production application. Before marking it as duplicate please hear me out. The previous questions asked are very old and since its almost been an decade i decide to raise this issue again hoping that there is an solution currently.

> What i want to achieve

[image: Example by setting a fixed height]

> What i am getting by setting height to wrap content

[image]